# How to use Bazel in Azure Pipelines?

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, bazel

I tried to set up an Azure Build Pipeline that uses [Bazel](https://bazel.build/) (0.26.0)

My pipeline YAML definition file looks like this:

```
trigger:
- master

pool:
  vmImage: 'windows-2019'

steps:
- script: echo Hello, world!
  displayName: 'Run a one-line script'

- script: |
    bazel version
    echo Add other tasks to build, test, and deploy your project.
    echo See https://aka.ms/yaml
  displayName: 'Run a multi-line script'
```

Currently, I try only to find out which Bazel version is installed by calling `bazel version` - but Azure DevOps reports:

```
'bazel' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
Cmd.exe exited with code '9009'.
```

I wonder how I can install and run Bazel in a Azure pipeline - any hints on this?

It seems that [this project](https://github.com/bazelbuild/rules_dotnet/blob/master/azure-pipelines.yml) got it working. But I do not understand how.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You got this error because you use Microsoft-hosted agent, in those agents `bazel` is not installed. In the example you provided they use Self Hosted (Private) Agent and they install `bazel` in their agent machine.

1) Install Self Hosted Agent in your private machine and install `bazel` in the machine.

2) Install `bazel` during the build pipeline with `choco` (simple script task):

```
choco install bazel
```

After you install it you can use it.

**P.S** I tried to install via `choco` and I got an error but `bazel` indeed installed and in the next step `bazel version` gave results, so in the installation task put `continueOnError = true`. (the error is in the python step, if your project not with python it's ok).

Comment: Just FYI it didn't error for me running the command as an inline Powershell command, but it did take 3 minutes to complete!

Answer (score 4):

Update in case anyone comes across this thread as of 2022:

Bazel is now installed on Microsoft-hosted agents for [`macOS-latest`](https://github.com/actions/virtual-environments/blob/main/images/macos/macos-11-Readme.md), [`ubuntu-latest`](https://github.com/actions/virtual-environments/blob/main/images/linux/Ubuntu2004-Readme.md), and [`windows-latest`](https://github.com/actions/virtual-environments/blob/main/images/win/Windows2022-Readme.md).

Try running this pipeline; you'll be able to see which version of Bazel is installed on each OS.

```yaml
strategy:
  matrix:
    linux:
      imageName: ubuntu-latest
    mac:
      imageName: macOS-latest
    windows:
      imageName: windows-latest

pool:
  vmImage: $(imageName)

steps:
  - script: bazel version
    displayName: Show bazel version
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how I install Bazel and Azure Pipeline on a `windows-2019` image:

```
steps:
  - script: |
      echo 'Install Bazel via Choco'
      choco install bazel
    displayName: 'Install dependencies'

  - script: |
      bazel version
    displayName: 'Show bazel version'
```

Answer (score 0):

In the meantime, Bazel and Bazelisk come already preinstalled. Seems Bazel takes over the world.

Tested and works with: `macOS-10.15`, `macOS-11`, `macOS-12`, `ubuntu-20.04`, `ubuntu-22.04`, `windows-2019`, `windows-2022`